# Catching unhandle exception in C++/CX

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is it possible to catch unhandle exception in C++/CX? I found that if crash happened in C++/CX my app will terminate immediately (Application_UnhandledException not get called). What's more, I found Win32 api SetUnhandledExceptionFilter is not avaliable which is Windows API for catching unhandle exception.

Comment: @Soonts, Well, after many research and tests, which include invoking private API SetUnhandledExceptionFilter, I finally resolve my problem by using [_set_se_translator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/5z4bw5h5)

Comment: Can you show an example, please?  I'm having a similar problem but my _set_se_translator function is not being called.

Answer (score 0):

If by *exception* you mean structured exceptions, you probably should use __try, e.g. something like this (untested code below):

```
__try
{
    someCode();
}
__except( EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER )
{
    throw Platform::Exception::CreateException( ... );
}
```

Or, if you're trying to handle a C++ exception, such as exceptions from STL, then you should catch them with try-catch statement, and throw `Platform::Exception` instead - this way they'll be correctly marshaled back into the managed code.

Comment: Thanks your answering.But I want to find some ways to get notified if  running code like this  "String *nulString = NULL; nulString->length();" which causing crash in C++/CX but not surrounded by try catch.

Comment: C and C++ is just too low-level, it was not designed for this kind of trickery. The native code is called “unsafe” for a reason: it is totally your responsibility to write code that among other things never call methods on null pointers. If you fail, anything can happen, including but not limited to e.g. data corruption or security issues.

Comment: But if you really know what you’re doing, the `__try  ..  __except` keywords should prevent the crash in this case. Or better yet, specify the `/Eha` compiler flag, and use `try { } catch (...)` C++ statements — with this flag `catch (...)` should catch the structured exceptions as well.